# How convert print in table csv beautiful soup

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup

the problem of my code is not save in the csv archive, create a csv but in blank. Using the print function show the results but not save in csv.

```
import csv
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "html"  
page = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
for tr in soup.find_all('tr')[2:]:
    tds = tr.find_all('h2') 
    td2 = tr.find_all('th')
    hora = tds[0].text.encode('utf-8')
    nombre = td2[0].text.encode('utf-8')
    print hora, nombre
    f = csv.writer(open("prueba.csv", "w"))
    f.writerow(["Hora", "Nombre"])
    f.writerow([hora, nombre])
```

Comment: I ran the code and it works for me. Make sure that `soup.find_all('tr')[2:]` isn't empty.

Comment: So it saves something? What is the content of the csv that you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The csv file that I get is:

> Hora,Nombre
>
> " Alaska y Segura ", 23:50
>
> 23:15

The reason is that you open the file in `w` mode every time you want to write to it. `w` mode replaces the content of a file if it already exists - it truncates the file, it does not append to the file. To append you should use `a` instead:

```
f = csv.writer(open("prueba.csv", "a"))
```

Another option, which is better since there is no need to close the file and reopen it again and again, is to only open the file once:

```
import csv
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = r"http://laguiatv.abc.es/programacion/tve-1-807.html"  
page = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
f = csv.writer(open("prueba.csv", "w"))
for tr in soup.find_all('tr')[2:]:
    tds = tr.find_all('h2') 
    td2 = tr.find_all('th')
    hora = tds[0].text.encode('utf-8')
    nombre = td2[0].text.encode('utf-8')
    print hora, nombre
    f.writerow(["Hora", "Nombre"])
    f.writerow([hora, nombre])
```

See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) for the `open` function:

> 'w' for writing (truncating the file if it already exists), and 'a' for appending

Answer (score 0):

```
1. import csv
2. import urllib2
3. from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
4. url = "html"  
5. page = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
6. soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
7. for tr in soup.find_all('tr')[2:]:
8.     tds = tr.find_all('h2') 
9.     td2 = tr.find_all('th')
10.    hora = tds[0].text.encode('utf-8')
11.    nombre = td2[0].text.encode('utf-8')
12.    print hora, nombre
13.    f = csv.writer(open("prueba.csv", "w"))
14.    f.writerow(["Hora", "Nombre"])
15.    f.writerow([hora, nombre])
```

A few suggestions.

1. in line 4, i hope you put "html" just for demo, as you need a url there
2. try putting line 13 before line 7 to prevent multiple file access, which may lead to error.

If you could give the url you are using, I'll try out and give better solutions.

Comment: No </div>, </table>, </tbody>?